# auto increasing id

Tags: php

I would like to build a php script that automatically generates a new id by increasing the previous by 1.
eg: A0009 becomes A0010 and A9999 becomes B0000

I have written one that works but it doesn't go over 5 chars long:
eg: Z9999 should go to A00000 and so on.

Any suggestions? 
here is my snippet:

```
<?php
function replaceChar($string2replace)
{
$charLength = strlen($string2replace)-1;
$charAt = array();
$charAt[4] = substr($string2replace, -1);
$charAt[3] = substr($string2replace, -2,1);
$charAt[2] = substr($string2replace, -3,1);
$charAt[1] = substr($string2replace, -4,1);
$charAt[0] = substr($string2replace, 0,1);

if($charAt[4] < 9)
{
$string2replace = substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[4]+1,$charLength);
}
else
{
$charAt[4] = 0;
$string2replace = substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[4],$charLength);
    if($charAt[3] < 9)
{
$string2replace = substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[3]+1,$charLength- 1,1);
}
else
{
$charAt[3] = 0;
$string2replace = substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[3],$charLength-1,1);

if($charAt[2] < 9)
{
$string2replace =  substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[2]+1,$charLength-2,1);
}
else
{
$charAt[2] = 0;
$string2replace = substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[2],$charLength-2,1);

if($charAt[1] < 9)
{
$string2replace = substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[1]+1,$charLength-3,1);
}
else
{
$charAt[1] = 0;
    $string2replace =    substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[1],$charLength-3,1);
    }

if($charAt[0] < 'z')
{
$charAt[0] ++;
$string2replace =    substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[0],$charLength-4,1);
}
else
{
$charAt[0] = 'a';
$string2replace =  substr_replace($string2replace,$charAt[0],$charLength-4,1);
}
}   
}
}
return $string2replace;
}

$string2begin = 'A9999';

$generatedString = replaceChar($string2begin);

echo $string2begin . "<br />" . $generatedString;


?>
```

Comment: Is your id column a pure hex value? What is one lower than A000?

Comment: Why doesn't A9999 + 1 = A999A?

Comment: @Gustav: It's obviously not "pure hex", as a value of `Z9999` is mentioned. Unless things have changed recently, `Z` isn't  a valid hex digit. :-)

Comment: I was hoping I misunderstood the question, and that he really wanted hex. The system appears to be one digit of base 26, and the rest of the digits are base 10. What kind of messed up system is that?!

Comment: The pattern seems to be that the first digit is always an uppercase letter. The system should theoretically continue Z99,999 -> A,000,000 and Z,999,999 -> A0,000,000. (Commas added to aid readability.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ID numbering scheme seems rather contrived, where the high-order digit is `A-Z` and the remaining digits are `0-9`. If I understand that pattern correctly, this seems to do the trick:

```
function incrementID($id)
{
    $letter = $id[0];
    $number = substr($id, 1);

    $newNum = str_pad($number + 1, strlen($number), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // increase number only
    if (strlen($number) == strlen($newNum))
        return $letter . $newNum;

    // increase ID length ('Z' to 'A')
    if ($letter == 'Z')
        return 'A' . str_repeat('0', strlen($number) + 1);

    // change letter
    $newLetter = chr(ord($letter) + 1);
    return $newLetter . str_repeat('0', strlen($number));

}

printf("%s\n", incrementID('A0009')); // 'A0010'
printf("%s\n", incrementID('A9999')); // 'B0000'
printf("%s\n", incrementID('Z9999')); // 'A00000'
```

---

Even though your examples didn't fit this, I first assumed you really just wanted a base-36 number (any digit could be `0-9,A-Z`, where `A` is 10 and `Z` is 35). Working with numbers in base-36 is easy because you can use [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/base_convert) to convert them to customary base-10. This is all you would need to do to increment base-36 numbers:

```
function incrementBase36($id)
{
    $numVal = base_convert($id, 36, 10);
    $newId = base_convert($numVal + 1, 10, 36);
    return strtoupper($newId);
}

printf("%s\n", incrementBase36('A0009')); // 'A000A'
printf("%s\n", incrementBase36('A9999')); // 'A999A'
printf("%s\n", incrementBase36('Z9999')); // 'Z999A'
printf("%s\n", incrementBase36('AZZZZ')); // 'B0000'
printf("%s\n", incrementBase36('ZZZZZ')); // '100000'
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, yes this does answer my question